# Image aligning problems

Tags: html, css

I have made a list with few elements in it.

Now everything looks right, except image, if i try to add at least one image i get all list messed up, i could use `div` instead of `img` tag but i need to resize that image all the time.

Iv'e been at this four couple hours now and i just can't figure out what's causing this, here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/QwcG5/1/ i hope some one can help me :)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Zeta well i think it's quite obvious blocks to the right should be in the same line as the first one that contains image, you can see how right border have gone down a lot.

Comment: see my answer and let me if any issues or is this not your requirement. Please specify if any changes you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the fiddle and demo:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QwcG5/13/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QwcG5/13/embedded/result/

I have set the entire layout fluid and it will not break the columns in next line both the li's will be in there respective `<li>` only.

Note: No modification in structure.

Comment: this breaks as soon as you resize the window for some pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Add vertical-align: middle; and it will be OK. http://jsfiddle.net/QwcG5/16/
I would also suggest replacing these divs

```
<div class="verify_list_block">1</div>
```

with li's and enclosing the whole thing in a separate ul. seems cleaner that way.

```
<li class="verify_list_item">
<ul class="info">
<li class="verify_list_block">1</li>
<li class="verify_list_block">3</li>
<li class="verify_list_block">4</li>
<li class="verify_list_block">5</li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: i have not change the structure. and in your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QwcG5/16/ when we zoom-in or zoom-out div(columns) are breaking to another line.

Comment: My layout is relatively flexible: When there is not enough space, the items go on the next line. What happens with yours is that everything is shifted towards the bottom. You're using vertical-align: top;  where you should be using vertical-align: middle; .-